# Problems with creating 'dead center' as jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, position, center, css-position

I'm working on very, very simple jQuery plugin that simply changes position of element to the center of browser's window (horizontally and vertically). Often this is called 'dead center'.

```
jQuery.fn.dead_center = function() {

    var element;

    element = this;

    $(element).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: ($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2,
        left: ($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2
    });

}
```

Then I have `<div />` with `<h1 />` in it like this:

```
<div class="dead_center">
    <h1>Foo and bars.</h1>
</div>
```

At the end, I call my 'plugin' like this:

```
$(function() {

    $('.dead_center').dead_center();

});
```

Problem is that `$('.dead_center')` is only center on y-axis. Not x-axis!

Why this happens? Can't spot my mistake.

Thanks in any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for a `div` is 100% width. (It's actually `auto`, but that's how `auto` works for block-level elements). So, it *is* centered horizontally. It's just taking up the whole horizontal area. Give the `div` a width, and you'll see.